# grep not working in script

Tags: bash, grep, sh

I have a very simple script that I'm trying to do a grep command in a bash script.  It works on the command line but not in the script.  I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "test 2";

grep 14784 logs/ftp_log.13-10-29 > test
```

It's called from a php page, it prints out the "test 2" but does not do the grep and create the test file, however when I run it from the command line it does without a problem.  Any help you could give would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Dave

Comment: What do you think is the current directory when the script is invoked from the PHP script? Did you try specifying absolute paths for the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a file permission problem. Make sure that the file `test` exists and the web server user has proper permissions to write to that file

Comment: shouldn't it be able to create a file if no file exists?

Comment: if the web server isn't the owner of the directory or is allowed to write to it (what is usual for security reasons) - no